# How can I help a new mother cat during her nursing period?

Tags: cats, health

Is there anything that I can do for her?

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

*Note: This question is a repost from [Is there a way to treat milk fever at home?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/is-there-a-way-to-treat-milk-fever-at-home). I'm reposting to allow one of the contributors (Violet) to repost their great answer, since the original post had multiple questions...*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you, Carlos! What can you do to help? The good news is mother cats are usually pretty perfect at it. But there are things you can do if the mother will let you.

Can you get a kitchen scale (calibrated in grams or ounces) and weigh the kittens once or twice a day? Steady weight gains is the best way to know they're healthy.

Make a chart so you can keep track of each kitten's weight. Ideally they should double their birth weight in the first week. In your case you don't have an exact birth weight, so make allowances for that.

What that means in daily gains: an average of about 1/4 to 1/2 ounce per day, or double-digit grams. For instance if a kitten weighs 100 grams at birth, he should gain another 100 grams during the first week, which is an average of about 100/7 or 14 grams per day.

There will be natural variation in this, so don't worry if a kitten occasionally gains less or even loses a little bit from one weighing to the next.

Sometimes a kitten will have trouble getting the hang of latching onto his mother's nipple. Maybe he keeps falling off, or he gets jostled off a lot by his siblings. If you notice this, you can try to help if the mother will let you. Manually hold the kitten at a nipple long enough for him to figure it out. Sometimes every nipple won't have milk, so find one that does.

If a particular kitten is consistently not gaining well, it's sometimes necessary to supplement with formula. Go to a pet store and buy kitten milk replacement, and bottles specially made for newborn kittens. A popular brand is KMR. It's important to only feed them formula that's intended for newborn kittens. As others have said, do not give kittens or cats cow's milk, egg yolk, or human infant formula, or anything else that's not especially made for kittens.

If you must do this, don't put the kitten on her back to give her the bottle. This can cause serious problems. Copy the natural position she'd use to nurse from her mother: on her stomach at a slight upward angle to the bottle. Make sure to always keep milk covering the part of the bottle near the nipple, so she won't drink air.

It's perfectly natural for kittens to wrestle and fight with each other while nursing. Do not worry about this at all unless one kitten is consistently being pushed away and isn't gaining weight.

It's also normal for kittens to twitch. It looks strange, but this is their nervous system's way of learning how their legs work.

Another thing you might find interesting is that newborn kittens can't go to the bathroom by themselves while they're tiny. That's why you see their mother licking their bottoms. If they were orphans, you'd have to do that yourself every few hours, so thank goodness mom is there!

Good luck!

(Of course it will be best if you can have your mother cat spayed after the kittens are weaned. Ask around - there might be a low cost spay-neuter clinic, or even make phone calls to see if any vet will do this at a reduced rate. (I do understand that it might be unaffordable - this is a very widespread problem.)

Comment: Can you prevent your mother cat from getting out of the house? Unfortunately mothers can get pregnant again while they're still nursing the first litter.

Comment: Not really. :/ She actually begs to go outside. She's a bit too used to it. The good thing is that she stays within sight when she does go out, and she's not leaving the litter for more than 1-2 hours at a time. She always comes back in to check on the babies, even if she goes out again a few minutes later.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure the she gets all the food and water she need,you can give her food for junior cats in the time she is nursing her kittens.

If you want you can put the food and water in the same room as where the kittens are,so your cat can see her kittens from where the food is.

Catfood for junior cats has a higher energy content than regular catfood so this will help her take care of her babies in the best way possible.

Be sure she has a safe area in a quiet place in your house so she can take care of her kittens whithout getting interrupted.except from this there is not a lot you need to do she is the expert here so all you need to do is keep an eye on things.

**if** your cat has a low level of calcium you can feed her powdered eggshell,you can make this by drying eggshell at 60C and running it in a blender until it is a powder.

sprinkle a tiny bit of this on her wet food every day while she is nursing.

Comment: This is a good point by Trond - your mother cat should eat kitten food while she's nursing. The kittens should get kitten food until they're one year old (see this article: pets.webmd.com/cats/guide/feeding-your-kitten-food-and-treats#1).

Comment: If your mother cat is eating well, and it's good-quality food - I'm not sure she needs calcium supplements unless she's actually been diagnosed with low blood calcium. Too much calcium can cause kidney and other problems. "Supplementing with calcium during pregnancy or nursing is not generally recommended." [See here](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/eclampsia-in-cats#:~:text=Can eclampsia be prevented%3F,blood calcium levels or eclampsia.)

Comment: (Trond did say "a tiny bit" - not trying to start an argument.)

Comment: Thank you trond! I've been doing a lot of this based on feedback from the original post (linked in the question). I'll keep the eggshells in mind, too, since I didn't know about that one! Luckily the mother+kitten food has been helping her a lot. I appreciate the information. ^^

Comment: i am not telling you to give calcium suplements because i think your cat need it but if the cat has been diagnosed with low levels of calcium eggshells will help get the calcium level back up to normal,an other way to be sure your cat have a healthy level of cacium is by giving fish oil(not codliver oil)with omega3 fatty acids,but again this is not something i think your cat need in this situation.