# My cat who just gave birth for the first time to 3 kittens stopped caring about them and has rapid breathing

Tags: cats, behavior

Today My cat Maša gave birth to 5 kittens, but 2 of them didnt make it. It took some time and we got worried, so we called the vet, who suggested giving a shot of some medicine that should help with getting the little kittens out. When we came, everything went well. Cant and her kittens were in a big box with some towels that we changed a few times. about 5-7 hours pass and she put them in our closet and just left them there. She laid down on our bed with us and started breathing rapidly, like really fast, sticking her tongue out like a dog, which made us think that she feels hot and wants to cool herself that way. Now we dont know wy she left them, and why is she breathing so fast. Her pupils are wide open and dont shrink. We tried to call a vet but its very late and nobody is responding. What went wrong? (sorry for bad english).

Comment: Panting isn't just from being too hot (though it can be that.) Panting is also a sign of stress. That along with the dilated eyes means the cat is in pain. I don't know anything about cats giving birth. If not your vet, I would try to find some vet you can contact.

Comment: you need to get your cat to the vet,it is the only advice i can give as this is an emrgency.

Comment: IF THE VET decides it is milk fever, you can look here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/is-there-a-way-to-treat-milk-fever-at-home